# iOS странным образом выводит блоки

Tags: html, css, ios

Имеется вот такое поведение:[image: https://yadi.sk/i/mPJMpSx13Tc698.]
С чем это связано? Почему ios дублирует некоторые блоки, заменяя при этом другие, да еще "пережевывая" подобным образом?

Comment: без кода не понять

Comment: Код большой, сюда не выложу. Но могу оставить ссылку на страницу: https://maksimradziuk.github.io/toyokawa/history.html

Comment: У меня в симуляторах не воспроизводится, а пока не воспроизведешь - багу не починишь) так что подключайте девайс, на котором воспроизводится к маку, через сафари дебажте

Comment: Если бы у меня он был))) А так он только у заказчика...

Comment: Скорей всего что-то не правильно с переиспользованием ячеек в коллекции. Видимо подсчет высоты производится для одной ячейки, а отображается другая.

Comment: Немного не понял) Можете рассказать подробнее о переиспользовании ячеек  и подсчете высоты в iOS (лучше ссылку на источник), спасибо.